# Where the file "firebase.json" goes in React-Native-Firebase V6

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

The React-Native-Firebase V6 documentation doesn't specify where to create the file, `firebase.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^0.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^0.1.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^0.1.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^0.1.2",
    "matter-js": "^0.14.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-game-engine": "^0.11.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-radial-gradient": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-share": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
 },
```

#### The following errors occur in the console:

- Where:

  - > Build file 'D:\Jesus\IFEEP AT\StoreClicker\StoreSkinClicker\node_modules@react-native-firebase\admob\android\build.gradle' line: 44
- What went wrong:

  - > A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-firebase_admob'.
    >   No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.getStringValue() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [admob_app_id, ]

Comment: The `firebase.json` file is used by the Firebase CLI. I don't immediately see anything in the message you get that points to needing a `firebase.json`. Are you sure you don't mean the `google-services.json`?

Comment: In the react-native-firebase documentation it says
`Add the ID to your root level firebase.json file under the react-native object:

{
  "react-native": {
    "admob_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}`

Comment: Interesting. I guess they use the file during the build. That says it needs to be in the root, so did you put it in the root of your project?

Comment: Yeah, I put it at the root of my project. In the same place where is my package.json

Answer (score 6):

`firebase.json` needs to go into the root of your react-native project. Same level as `package.json`.

If you run pod install for ios it will output a line:

`Using firebase.json from '<Path_To_Project>/firebase.json'`

I interpret it as the correct position...

This is how your firebase.json might look like:

```js
{
  "react-native": {
    "ml_vision_face_model": true,
    "ml_vision_ocr_model": true,
    "ml_vision_barcode_model": true,

    "ml_vision_label_model": true,
    "ml_vision_image_label_model": true
  }
}
```

Comment: This should really be in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: I am using v7 and there is no firebase.json file

Answer (score 0):

`.JSON` files are usually kept at the root in react native projects in their native folders and in android we keep that inside the `app` folder, and try giving them relative path.